# Namerror in python for self in the for loop ,

Tags: python-3.x, svm, python-3.6, nameerror

```
 class Support_Vector_Machine():
    def __init__(self, visualization=True):
     self.visualization = visualization
     self.colors = {1:'r',-1:'b'}
     if self.visualization:
         self.fig = plt.figure()
         self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
           # train
    def fit(self, data):
             self.data=data
             opt_dict = {}
             transforms = [[1,1],
             [-1,-1],[1,-1],[-1,1 ]]
             all_data=[]

    for yi in **self.data :**
             for featureset in  self.data[yi]:
                 for feature in featureset:
                     self.max_feature_value = max(all_data)
                     self.min_feature_value = min(all_data)
                     all_data= None
```

In the above code , I am trying to loop a variable yi through self.data which throws the name error.
Help me resolve the error.
it says:
line 21, in Support_Vector_Machine
    for yi in self.data :
NameError: name 'self' is not defined

Answer (score 1):

In Python, indentation matters. The whole `for` block is misindented:

```
class Support_Vector_Machine():
   def __init__(self, visualization=True):
       self.visualization = visualization
       self.colors = {1:'r',-1:'b'}
       if self.visualization:
           self.fig = plt.figure()
           self.ax = self.fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
           # train

   def fit(self, data):
       self.data=data
       opt_dict = {}
       transforms = [[1,1],
       [-1,-1],[1,-1],[-1,1 ]]
       all_data=[]

       for yi in self.data:
           for featureset in  self.data[yi]:
               for feature in featureset:
                    self.max_feature_value = max(all_data)
                    self.min_feature_value = min(all_data)
                    all_data= None
```